# Is there any way to receive data from service bus queue if condition satisfied?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-servicebus-queues

I want to receive data from a service bus queue if a condition satisfied.
Is there any way to achieve this? 
I have initiated QueueClient after the condition satisfied. But it does not work.

Comment: The question is very vague. Please provide more details about 1) what do you mean by "condition" 2) what have you already attempted 3) what doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a condition that checks the properties of a message, you are better off by using a Topic + Subscription instead of a Queue.

You would send messages to a topic and your application would have its own subscription with a [topic filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters) that takes messages from the topic based on the filter criteria.

There is a [Topic Subscription Filters (C#)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/TopicFilters) sample that you can refer to for its implementation.

Comment: Is there any Sample Project which I can refer?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/TopicFilters) is a sample that you can refer to.